# Escape quotes in alias

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I want to write an alias to quickly search for a filename in the current directory (case insensitive).

The following works:

```
alias f='find . -iname $@'
```

The problem is that when I want to use wilcards in the search expression, I need to quote them (otherwise zsh expansion handles the wildcard first):

```
> f podfi*
zsh: no matches found: podfi*
> f "podfi*"
./Podfile
```

How can I add the quotes in my alias so that `f podfi*` works ?

These tentatives do not work:

```
alias f='find . -iname "$@"'
alias f='find . -iname \"$@\"'
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do inside `alias` once shell has already expanded it. To avoid expanding globs you must quote it.

Comment: Why don't you simply define your alias as `alias f='find . -iname` and then use it with `f <something>`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I'd like to avoid the hassle of quoting the glob expression. As suggested by anubhava, the solution might not exist (or maybe it is feasible using a zsh feature more advanced than alias)

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry I did not pay enough attention. And I agree that it cannot work: the shell expands the globs before passing them to the command. But you can maybe substitute other characters to the `*`, `?`, and `[` that the pathname expansion considers. A bash function instead of an alias could then perform the opposite substitution and pass the result to find...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet This is a good idea for a workaround indeed.

Comment: I tried this: `alias f='GLOBIGNORE="*"; find . -iname'` and it seems to work. Not sure I fully understand why. But it modifies the GLOBIGNORE variable and it is probably not what you want. Anyway, there is probably something to explore here (bash options and variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this for zsh:

```
% alias f='noglob find . -iname $@'
% f podfi*
./Podfile
% f "podfi*"
./Podfile
%
```

Comment: Is this a `zsh`-only feature or does it also exist with `bash`? (I tried with GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release and got a `bash: noglob: command not found`).

Comment: Cool. Thanks. The drawback is that it is persistent while it does not seem to be in `zsh`. Anyway, I edit my own answer to use `set +/- f` instead of the less elegant and probably not as good `GLOBIGNORE`.

Comment: Alas, it does not work as I expected: the `set +f` that I wanted to put in my function has a local scope.

Comment: To be honest, I did not encounter the OP's problem with my bash (_GNU bash, version 4.3.11_). In zsh I did. I will dig a little more in it and see if there is anything related with this in my .bashrc

Comment: @Sebastien Thank you for your remarks. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
function ff () { find . -iname "$2"; GLOBIGNORE="$1"; }
alias f='s="$GLOBIGNORE"; GLOBIGNORE="*"; ff "$s"'
```

The alias saves the current value of `GLOBIGNORE`, sets `GLOBIGNORE` to `*`, and calls the `ff` function to which it passes the saved `GLOBIGNORE` as a first parameter. The `ff` function calls find with the unglobled alias parameter and restores `GLOBIGNORE`. Tested with GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release:

```
f *.tex
./full.tex
./hdr.tex
./main.tex
```